# VMware systems not working on SRW2048 swtich

Tags: networking, cisco, vmware-esxi, switch

I received an old Linksys SRW2048 gigabit switch and have used a straight-through serial cable and the console port to reset the flash config back to defaults so that it is configurable for our network.  I then upgraded it to the newest firmware (1.22d).

Currently I have 4 devices connected to it: a physical Windows server, physical Windows desktop, VMware ESXi 5.5 host with 2 Windows guests, and a printer.

The physical server, desktop and printer that are connected to the SRW2048 all have fully functioning networking.

I've found that the VMware Host (and guests) lose all networking.  If I connect the VMware host back to the temporary gigabit switch I was using, all networking for it and its guests resumes.

Where do I start troubleshooting the VMware-switch setup?
I haven't made any changes to the switch's default configuration except the static IP for managing it.

Answer (score 0):

Since I know that VMware strips VLAN assignments unless configured properly I would start there. If you have the new switch using VLAN and the old switch using direct ports then this would be the problem. In VMware you need to set the virtual switch to use all VLAN ports. Since you are only having problems with VMware I would pay close attention to the virtual switch settings and configuration. Hope this helps